# Campaign attribution for mobile app deep linking (UTMs /GA4)

Tags: ios, deep-linking, utm, google-analytics-4

Has anyone been able to successfully implement UTMs to deeplinks (iOS) and have them display in GA4?

I've followed this guide but for some reason they do not seem to show:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/mobile-campaign-deep-link

Would appreciate any guidance on how to track deeplinks and which channels drive them in GA4 for iOS.

Many thanks!

Ma1ch

Expecting to see the source/medium/campaign that we've added to deep links in GA4 so that we can measure the performance per channel.